# How do I install .NET Framework only when it's not already installed?

Tags: .net, inno-setup

Is there a way to check if the .NET Framework 4 has been installed and install it only when it's not in the system?

I know, how do I determine, if the .NET Framework 4 is installed by checking the following registry key?

```pascal
hasDotnet4 :=
  RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v4.0');
```

How do I conditionally run the .NET Framework 4 installation based on the above check?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Im using inno setup to detect if .net 4.0 client installed but it doesn't work well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008905/im-using-inno-setup-to-detect-if-net-4-0-client-installed-but-it-doesnt-work-w)

Comment: No, this is unique, just couldn't find any threads with this answer

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The easiest you can do, is to use the [`Check`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm) parameter, which allows you to control if a certain file from the [`[Files]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm) section will be extracted, or if a certain program from the [`[Run]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm) section will be executed. The following script code shows its usage for the conditional installation of the .NET Framework 4:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; \
  Flags: deleteafterinstall; Check: FrameworkIsNotInstalled

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe"; Check: FrameworkIsNotInstalled

[Code]

function FrameworkIsNotInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  Result :=
    not RegKeyExists(
      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v4.0');
end;
```

Comment: You could have the `Check:` statement even in the `[Files]` section directly to skip even the extraction step.

Comment: Why not with `ExpandConstant('{dotnet40}')` instead of direct registry access?

Comment: @i486, checking the registry key is better because you're not adding the exception handling overhead. Except that you can easily modify this code to detect a specific version, e.g. .NET 4.5.